# Is there a way to reset a class instance's initialized attribute to the value entered when the instance was created?

Tags: ruby, class

For example, I have:

```
class Camel
  attr_accessor :name, :meat_quality
  def initialize(name, meat_quality)
    name = @name
    meat_quality = @meat_quality
  end
end
```

And I initialize an instance `carlos`, and later change its `@meat_quality` value:

```
carlos = Camel.new("Carlos","orphan grade")

...

carlos.meat_quality = "public school grade"
```

Later, though, I need a way to refer to whatever was passed to `@meat_quality` when `carlos` was first initialized (namely `"tough and stringy"`).

I will be changing `@meat_quality` multiple times, so I can't just use default values or make a variable like `previous_quality`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but it's up to you to implement it, which is extremely trivial.

Comment: What a helpful answer! Also the guy below said it's _not_ possible. Shows what you know eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in Ruby that saves the initial value passed on, so nothing in Ruby that will let you automatically reset it. However, you can certainly save the value in an another instance variable and reset it as you wish, as in:

```
def initialize(..., meat_quality)
  ...
  @original_meat_quality = @meat_quality = meat_quality
end

def reset_meat_quality
  @meat_quality = @original_meat_quality
end
```